# Spark map creation takes a very long time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As shown below,

Step 1: Group the calls using groupBy

```
//Now group the calls by the s_msisdn for call type 1
//grouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, (Array[String], String))])] 
val groupedCallsToProcess = callsToProcess.groupBy(_._1)
```

Step 2: the grouped Calls are mapped.

```
//create a Map of the second element in the RDD, which is the callObject
//grouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String,(Array[String], String))])] 

val mapOfCalls = groupedCallsToProcess.map(f => f._2.toList)
```

Step 3: Map to the Row object, where the map will have key-value pair of [CallsObject, msisdn]

```
val listOfMappedCalls = mapOfCalls.map(f => f.map(_._2).map(c => 
  Row(
      c._1(CallCols.call_date_hour),
      c._1(CallCols.sw_id),   
      c._1(CallCols.s_imsi),
      f.map(_._1).take(1).mkString
    )
  ))
```

The 3rd step as shown above seems to take a very long time when the data size is very large. I am wondering if there is any way to make the step 3 efficient. Really appreciate any help in this.

Comment: Can you show your input and expected output? It's hard to follow what you are grouping by and mapping over

Comment: Why do you need to do `Array` to `List` map? `toList` operation is not only very costly on large collections but also leads to lot of GC-overhead.

Comment: So should step 2 just be : val mapOfCalls = groupedCallsToProcess.map(f => f._2) ?

Comment: Also... the first `map(_._2)` is totally wasteful. You don't need that. Remember every `map` on a list is a linear operation of the order of map function.

Comment: You do not need the second step. Just skip it and also remove the `map(_._2)` part in 3rd step.

Comment: Also, remember RDDs are lazy. The cause of the slowness may not be the code you think it is, but something you did earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of things that are very costly in your code which you actually don't need.

1. You do not need the `groupBy` in first step. `groupBy` are very costly in Spark.
2. The whole second step is useless. `toList` is very costly with lot of GC overhead.
3. Remove 1 extra map in third step. Every `map` is linear operation of the order of map function.
4. Never do something like `f.map(_._1).take(1)`. You are transforming the whole list but using only 1 (or 5) element. Instead do `f.take(5).map(_._1)`. And if you need only 1 - `f.head._1`.

Before discussing how can you write this code without `groupBy` in a different way, lets fix this code.

```
// you had this in start
val callsToProcess: RDD[(String, (Array[String], String))] = ....

// RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, (Array[String], String))])]
val groupedCallsToProcess = callsToProcess
  .groupBy(_._1)

// skip the second step

val listOfMappedCalls = groupedCallsToProcess
  .map({ case (key, iter) => {
    // this is what you did
    // val iterHeadString = iter.head._1
    // but the 1st element in each tuple of iter is actually same as key
    // so
    val iterHeadString = key
    // or we can totally remove this iterHeadString and use key
    iter.map({ case (str1, (arr, str2)) => Row(
      arr(CallCols.call_date_hour),
      arr(CallCols.sw_id),   
      arr(CallCols.s_imsi),
      iterHeadString
    ) })
  } })
```

But... like I said `groupBy` are very costly in Spark. And you already had a `RDD[(key, value)]` in your `callsToProcess`. So we can just use `aggregateByKey` directly. Also you may notice that your `groupBy` is not useful for anything else other than putting all those rows inside a list instead of directly inside and RDD.

```
// you had this in start
val callsToProcess: RDD[(String, (Array[String], String))] = ....

// new lets map it to look like what you needed because we can 
// totally do this without any grouping
// I somehow believe that you needed this RDD[Row] and not RDD[List[Row]]
// RDD[Row]
val mapped = callsToProcess
  .map({ case (key, (arr, str)) => Row(
      arr(CallCols.call_date_hour),
      arr(CallCols.sw_id),   
      arr(CallCols.s_imsi),
      key
  ) })


// Though I can not think of any reason of wanting this
// But if you really needed that RDD[List[Row]] thing...
// then keep the keys with your rows
// RDD[(String, Row)]
val mappedWithKey = callsToProcess
  .map({ case (key, (arr, str)) => (key, Row(
      arr(CallCols.call_date_hour),
      arr(CallCols.sw_id),   
      arr(CallCols.s_imsi),
      key
  )) })

// now aggregate by the key to create your lists
// RDD[List[Row]]
val yourStrangeRDD = mappedWithKey
  .aggregateByKey(List[Row]())(
    (list, row) => row +: list, // prepend, do not append
    (list1, list2) => list1 ++ list2
  )
```

Comment: value ++ is not a member of List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] any alternative

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: It was giving a compilation error, but its fixed now, after you fixed the last line. Also, please let me know if you are open for a parttime contract or hourly contract

Comment: Yes, earlier I made a mistake to use `:++` instead of `++`.